# Is there a way to send an HTTP Request's content via an HTTP Post Request?

Tags: java, http, post

The title says most of it. I'm trying to figure out how to pass all the data of an http request (header, body etc..) and send it through another http request but I can't figure out how to do that.
I have tried to do the following

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(uri +"/Request"))
                .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("Example of body"))
                .build();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(request);
        oos.flush();
        byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();
                
        HttpRequest sending = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(uri +"/Request"))
            .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray(data))
            .build();

        
        
        try {
            HttpResponse<byte[]> response = httpClient.send(sending, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());
            
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but it doesn't work because the HttpRequest class is immutable. What I did there is create an Http Request (Post request) which i'd like to put in another Post request's body. To do so, I convert it to an array of bytes then I send it in the try-catch block.

Any ideas, please ? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to transfer a whole HTTP request (body, header etc.) inside the body of another HTTP request as if it was the data you want to post to your service? Or do you simply want to copy request 1 into request 2?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Hello, I want the whole HTTP request as if it was the data the other request will use as body

Comment: What does the receiving service (the one to which you post the request) want to do with the HTTP request you send? Also, do you own that service?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I work on two different platforms. My goal is to transfer the HTTP request as is, without any parsing, from platform A to platform B. The parsing will be done when it has reached platform B (receiving service). The receiving service will just use the http request to execute a few operations.
To answer the second question: Yes, I own the service

Comment: Whatever you transfer from service A to service B through HTTP is supposed to be serializable, but the object HttpRequest provided by java.net is not. I would suggest you create a Json representation of your HTTP request in service A and that's what you transfer in the body of the request for service B, that will on its side be able to parse this content and rebuild the HTTP request correctly.

Comment: An HttpRequest is immutable, but an HttpRequest.Builder is not.  You can use a Builder to create multiple requests, and you can modify the Builder as much as you wish between the creation of those requests.